# Baking with lemon curd: when is it set?

Tags: baking

I was trying out a new recipe which are shortbread squares with a layer of cranberry preserves topped by a thin (~1 cm) layer of lemon curd. After pouring on the curd, the recipe says to cook at 300 degrees F "until curd is set (about 10 mins)."

I have no idea what this means. I tried googling and found a variety of methods, none of which seemed very official/scientific and all of which seemed to be tailored to the recipe they were associated with. A lemon tart recipe said to gently tap the crust and look to see if the curd in the center jiggled (i have no crust). Another said to apply a "thumbprint test" but didn't elaborate on what that was. A [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44610/how-to-know-when-to-remove-lemon-squares-from-oven) on this site about lemon bars suggested an internal temperature of 83C, but I couldn't get my thermometer to give a reliable reading given how thin the layer of curd was.

I ended up taking it out at 15 minutes, when a gentle shake of the pan seemed to be only slightly jiggly (and my highly unreliable thermometer said 139F which is probably not correct.)

When a recipe says to bake until curd is set like above, how do I know it is set? This curd was made by whisking together butter, sugar, egg yolks, and lemon juice, and thickening it over low heat in the stove.

Comment: I guess this question could be phrased "if i can't take the temperature, how do I know if it's set?"

Comment: Also I've never cooked with curd before -- pretty sure I've never even eaten curd before -- so i really am clueless about this whole process. :)